# Jasmine test event with asynchronous call

Tags: jasmine, twitter-flight

The issue is to test the event handlers with asynchronous internal methods, which is executed by SDK like facebook.

the plain test is:

```
describe('Listens to someevent', function () {


       it('and triggers anotherevent', function () {
            var eventSpy = spyOnEvent(document, 'anotherevent');
            var data = {
              param1: 'param1',
              param2: 'param2',

            }
            this.component.trigger('somevent', data);

            runs(function() {
                expect(eventSpy).toHaveBeenTriggeredOn(document);
            });

        });
      });
```

when someevent is triggered with options, the component handler is fired:

```
this.handler = function (e, data) {

     SDK.apicall(data, function (err, response) {

                    if (!err) {
                        doSomething();
                    }

                    // trigger data event
                    that.trigger(document, 'anotherevent');

                });

            }
            ;

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

In jasmine 1.3 and before, a `runs` without a preceding `waitsFor` still executes immediately. It's really the `waitsFor` that makes the spec asynchronous. This has [changed in 2.0](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support).

Alternatively, if you don't really want to call the external API during your tests. You can use something like [jasmine-ajax](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-ajax) ([docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/ajax.html)). This will allow you to return the ajax call immediately in test with whatever response you want to test with. This has the advantage of making your specs faster (there's no waiting for the API), and make your specs less dependent on the API being up when they run.